# What socket.emit do in node js?

Tags: html, node.js, socket.io

Can anyone tell me what this does in Node.js?

```
socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
```

Comment: Client doc is at https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-emit-eventName-%E2%80%A6args-ack. Server doc is at https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-emit-eventName-%E2%80%A6args-ack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sends a socket.io webSocket message to a server that you are connected with.

Here's a breakdown of the pieces.

`socket` is the socket.io connection that the client has previously set up with the server

`chat message` is a message identifier that the server is listening for (it can be anything you want)

`$('#m').val()` says to get the `.value` property from the DOM element with `id="m"` and send that as the content of the message

Comment: @UmeshSonawane - If your question got answered, then you can select the best answer and indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of that answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Without the context, my best guess would be that the code attaches an event emitter of name 'chat message' and emit the value of div which has id as 'm'.

Comment: The context was specified by the tag: [socket.io]